# Create a draft reply message give an error on providing payload

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am hitting the Outlook Office 365 API through Postman. I tried to create a draft reply message using this URL:

`POST https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{message_id}/createreply`

The body contained:

```json
body: {
  "Comment": "Sounds great! See you tomorrow."
}
```

but I got the following error:

```json
{
   "error": {
      "code": "RequestBodyRead",
        "message": "The parameter 'Comment' in the request payload is not a valid parameter for the operation 'CreateReply'."
    }
}
```

I have used this call based on the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#reply-or-reply-all-to-messages).

This issue also exists for create a draft reply all message and create a draft forward message.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're placing `comment` within the `body`, it should stand on it's own. From this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#CreateReplyDraft):

```
POST https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/messages/AAMkADA1MTAAAAqldOAAA=/createreply
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "Comment": "Fanny, Randi, would you name the group if the project is approved, please?" 
}
```

Note that it is `{"comment": "string"}` and not `body:{"comment": "string"}`.